# Is it possible to reference ModelContext of an existing Project inside generated Controllers with Sourcegenerators

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I'm currently playing around with SourceGenerators and want to create a controller for each model of an existing DBContext.

I kickstarted the project with Scaffold-DbContext DemoDatabase and added the Person controller and the API is working fine. The project is in net6.0 and the generator is in netstandard2.0.

My handwritten Controller in the API Project looks exactly the same as the generated Code.

I managed to create the following file via the SourceGenerator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Deltas;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;
using DemoApi.Models;

namespace DemoApi.Controllers.v3
{

    public partial class PersonController : ODataController
    {
        private ModelContext _context;

        public PersonController(ModelContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Person.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

However VisualStudio outputs an Error stating that the ModelContext does not contain a definition for Person. Either the syntax highlighting is not working properly or the I'm missing something because I can't navigate the generated files (eg. pressing F12 on ODataController just outputs: Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.)

Are there any possible way for the generated files to recognize the existing ModelContext because referncing is via `using DemoApi.Models` did not work or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a mapping issue between the c# dbContext models and the database that is being used.  What is the connection string for the model?

Comment: @jdweng As I mentioned above, the controller is valid and working when manually added to the API. There are no connection or mapping issues if I create the controller Class manually and drop it in the controllers folder.

Comment: See following including the Migration link.  You may need to run migration : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: @jdweng I have a dbContext model with the Person DbContext and the Person model as a class. EFCore is working as expected but it does not resolve the issue I'm having. I can reference the gernerated file in the api but the generated File itself doesn't know the context of the api.

Comment: The API needs to get a "reference" of the context that contains data.  So when API needs context pass as a parameter in the method or add as a parameter to the constructor.